# SQL Conditional Statements - IF

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The below SQL report displays bus routes (masterline table) providing service to a train station (GoAbbr), named ARGO, and the times the routes service it (st.ETime column). Since not all bus routes are not starting its trips at ARGO, I included the bus routes start time (t.FromTime column).

**ISSUE**

The bus route 31 starts at ARGO, services several bus stops and ends at ARGO. The bus route 222 starts at ARGO and ends at a different location. When I run the SQL report, it produces a result like this:

```
Line    FromTime    ETime
----    --------    -----
031     16:41       16:41 
031     16:41       17:11     
222     17:41       17:41
```

As you can see, the SQL report is showing two results for the Route 31 trip departing ARGO 16:41 and arriving at ARGO at 17:11, which technically it's suppose to do. However, I want to eliminate the Route 31 result that shows duplicate FromTime and ETime. Now, I could add this to my SQL WHERE statement:

```
t.FromTime <> st.ETime
```

But that would eliminate the Route 222 result, which I don't want to happen. I've tried searching for an answer but I'm at a loss. Can anyone help?

**SQL STATEMENT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT

sup.signupname, msg.servicegroupabbr, ml.lineabbr, l.DirectionName, 
s.stopabbr, s.stopname, t.FromTime, st.ETime, 'ARGO' as GoAbbr

FROM 

trips t, linestop ls, stoptimes st, masterservicegroup msg, signupperiods 
sup, stops s, masterline ml, line l

WHERE 

t.signid = sup.signid and
t.signid = ls.signid and
t.linedirid = ls.linedirid and
t.linedirid = l.linedirid and
l.lineid = ml.lineid and
t.tripid = st.tripid and
ls.stopnum = st.stopnum and
t.servicegroupid = msg.servicegroupid and
ls.stopid = s.stopid and
s.stopabbr IN ('6424','6423','5253','1745','1759') and
ml.lineabbr IN ('031','032','033','033A','054','222') and

order by 

s.stopabbr, ml.lineabbr,st.ETime
```

**EXAMPLE OF OUTCOME:**
[image]

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for more than 20 years.

Comment: apart from using ancient join styles, it would help if you would post sample data and desired outcome for that sample data

Comment: I have attached an example of the sample data and desired outcome. I also highlighted the areas that I explained in my post. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this, is use `row_number` function, then have it partition by `linedirid, FromTime, ETime`, something like this, also use proper `join`
Give it a shot, fix joins if needed and let us know how it worked

```
  SELECT rownums, signupname, servicegroupabbr, lineabbr, 
         DirectionName, stopabbr, stopname, FromTime, 
         ETime, GoAbbr 
  FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                  (PARTITION BY t.linedirid, t.FromTime, st.ETime 
                                   ORDER BY t.linedirid) rownums,
                      sup.signupname, 
                      msg.servicegroupabbr, 
                      ml.lineabbr, 
                      l.DirectionName, 
                      s.stopabbr, 
                      s.stopname, 
                      t.FromTime, 
                      st.ETime, 
                      'ARGO' as GoAbbr
      FROM trips t
        JOIN linestop ls            ON t.signid = ls.signid and
                                       t.linedirid = ls.linedirid and                    
        JOIN stops s                ON ls.stopid = s.stopid and 
                                       s.stopabbr IN ('6424','6423',
                                                      '5253','1745','1759')
        JOIN line l                 ON t.linedirid = l.linedirid
        JOIN stoptimes st           ON t.tripid = st.tripid and
                                       ls.stopnum = st.stopnum
        JOIN masterservicegroup msg ON msg.servicegroupid = t.servicegroupid, 
        JOIN signupperiods sup      ON t.signid = sup.signid
        JOIN masterline ml          ON l.lineid = ml.lineid annd
                                       ml.lineabbr IN ('031','032','033',
                                                       '033A','054','222')) src
  WHERE rownums = 1
  ORDER BY stopabbr, lineabbr, ETime
```